# How to create a barplot based on a condition in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I have the following code:

```
set.seed(123)

CIS_data_5 <- data.frame(
  CIS$P20,
  CIS$P3
)

CIS$P3 <- factor(CIS$P3, labels = c("Mejor", "(NO LEER) Igual", "Peor", "N.S.", "N.C."))

n <- as.numeric(c(CIS$P20))
P20 <- sample(n, 2787, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)

P20labs <- c("16-29", "30-44", "45-64", ">65", "N.C.")
cut_points <- c(16, 30, 45, 65, Inf)

i <- findInterval(P20, cut_points)
P20_fac <- P20labs[i]
P20_fac[is.na(P20)] <- P20labs[length(P20labs)]
P20_fac <- factor(P20_fac, levels = P20labs)
```

where `P3` has 5 categories, indicating the socioeconomic perception of a sample of Spanish population, and `P20_fac` has 5 other categories that indicate the age of the respondents.

My desired outcome would be to have 5 joint graphs, in which the socioeconomic situation (`P3`) is reflected according to the age of the respondents (`P20_fac`).

I have been stuck on thinking how I can possibly represent this graphically, and after many an hour spent, I have completely run out of ideas (though I think that it can somehow be done by means of `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()`).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Regarding *what is my question*, I have already stated that "My desired outcome would be to have 5 (grouped together) graphs, in which the socioeconomic situation (`P3`) is represented **based on** the age of the respondents (`P20_fac`)."
If I knew how to answer it, I most surely would not be making this question on this forum.

**UPDATE**

The closest that I've got to the desired result is by running the following code:

```
plot(CIS$P3 ~ P20_fac, data = CIS)
```

However, it only gets me the graphical results for the first age interval ("16-29") and in vertical instead of horizontal form.

**dput(CIS_data_5)**

```
> dput(CIS_data_5)
structure(list(CIS.P20 = structure(c(48L, 33L, 28L, 36L, 32L, 
24L, 27L, 50L, 55L, 34L, 48L, 22L, 37L, 24L, 35L, 35L, 19L, 57L, 
32L, 45L, 13L, 23L, 24L, 5L, 8L, 34L, 2L, 52L, 66L, 43L, 54L, 
24L, 27L, 40L, 40L, 64L, 29L, 12L, 52L, 7L, 26L, 40L, 59L, 19L, 
24L, 44L, 19L, 62L, 26L, 16L, 40L, 31L, 14L, 15L, 29L, 24L, 41L, 
33L, 41L, 3L, 39L, 4L, 44L, 39L, 1L, 28L, 40L, 8L, 49L, 59L, 
50L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 41L, 35L, 35L, 65L, 40L, 38L, 29L, 24L, 54L, 
40L, 21L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 45L, 50L, 27L, 50L, 60L, 50L, 41L, 56L, 
57L, 33L, 45L, 31L, 58L, 3L, 16L, 43L, 25L, 40L, 32L, 17L, 58L, 
46L, 15L, 40L, 22L, 28L, 11L, 38L, 50L, 22L, 25L, 47L, 17L, 32L, 
36L, 49L, 40L, 23L, 17L, 34L, 8L, 37L, 67L, 37L, 52L, 60L, 5L, 
55L, 45L, 40L, 36L, 46L, 50L, 13L, 73L, 31L, 33L, 47L, 58L, 37L, 
55L, 16L, 38L, 32L, 15L, 45L, 33L, 9L, 47L, 10L, 9L, 33L, 41L, 
31L, 31L, 21L, 28L, 26L, 68L, 15L, 63L, 38L, 59L, 30L, 47L, 21L, 
36L, 50L, 40L, 30L, 14L, 54L, 16L, 60L, 8L, 44L, 49L, 68L, 33L, 
24L, 58L, 27L, 34L, 33L, 47L, 50L, 52L, 15L, 21L, 16L, 47L, 59L, 
37L, 34L, 11L, 37L, 50L, 9L, 41L, 51L, 31L, 35L, 26L, 5L, 24L, 
51L, 6L, 27L, 52L, 68L, 8L, 39L, 33L, 51L, 41L, 53L, 39L, 60L, 
43L, 10L, 51L, 26L, 41L, 51L, 54L, 35L, 33L, 35L, 39L, 28L, 48L, 
5L, 31L, 50L, 8L, 45L, 50L, 41L, 53L, 54L, 32L, 43L, 65L, 22L, 
32L, 24L, 35L, 40L, 34L, 41L, 19L, 48L, 46L, 35L, 24L, 12L, 35L, 
19L, 8L, 30L, 58L, 55L, 16L, 37L, 17L, 1L, 35L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 
53L, 50L, 42L, 37L, 29L, 54L, 4L, 29L, 47L, 51L, 58L, 10L, 29L, 
36L, 16L, 9L, 54L, 36L, 19L, 49L, 59L, 39L, 6L, 35L, 25L, 52L, 
3L, 47L, 52L, 51L, 26L, 65L, 23L, 35L, 45L, 55L, 45L, 9L, 19L, 
32L, 49L, 47L, 45L, 7L, 31L, 24L, 7L, 21L, 45L, 52L, 57L, 37L, 
56L, 39L, 26L, 46L, 35L, 35L, 4L, 20L, 21L, 45L, 23L, 20L, 41L, 
23L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 60L, 43L, 27L, 56L, 38L, 44L, 35L, 14L, 58L, 
50L, 29L, 25L, 15L, 10L, 57L, 61L, 46L, 43L, 23L, 29L, 57L, 24L, 
32L, 36L, 33L, 34L, 31L, 60L, 4L, 42L, 43L, 41L, 51L, 29L, 10L, 
29L, 48L, 29L, 37L, 62L, 17L, 37L, 45L, 17L, 47L, 53L, 10L, 35L, 
8L, 25L, 32L, 51L, 46L, 39L, 46L, 48L, 4L, 35L, 34L, 37L, 3L, 
6L, 74L, 13L, 60L, 36L, 1L, 33L, 13L, 23L, 42L, 60L, 39L, 66L, 
49L, 50L, 57L, 41L, 16L, 23L, 28L, 6L, 45L, 53L, 21L, 26L, 40L, 
21L, 34L, 37L, 6L, 50L, 48L, 28L, 62L, 50L, 48L, 28L, 14L, 31L, 
44L, 17L, 26L, 46L, 17L, 11L, 55L, 24L, 33L, 30L, 52L, 22L, 40L, 
43L, 29L, 36L, 60L, 5L, 45L, 33L, 44L, 35L, 32L, 19L, 51L, 19L, 
29L, 24L, 35L, 28L, 42L, 6L, 42L, 63L, 19L, 11L, 56L, 48L, 8L, 
12L, 30L, 12L, 48L, 56L, 20L, 54L, 32L, 64L, 42L, 44L, 28L, 26L, 
42L, 48L, 33L, 46L, 46L, 23L, 28L, 64L, 25L, 19L, 26L, 3L, 31L, 
49L, 40L, 65L, 28L, 20L, 47L, 24L, 71L, 13L, 34L, 48L, 27L, 43L, 
1L, 28L, 56L, 24L, 25L, 29L, 43L, 54L, 55L, 29L, 38L, 56L, 27L, 
72L, 47L, 25L, 34L, 23L, 15L, 37L, 18L, 55L, 49L, 39L, 32L, 54L, 
14L, 34L, 14L, 21L, 3L, 56L, 24L, 32L, 38L, 50L, 68L, 44L, 12L, 
30L, 29L, 58L, 31L, 51L, 33L, 38L, 48L, 27L, 55L, 62L, 12L, 29L, 
71L, 38L, 61L, 48L, 45L, 55L, 23L, 58L, 37L, 55L, 5L, 51L, 20L, 
10L, 30L, 60L, 39L, 40L, 21L, 44L, 16L, 25L, 15L, 47L, 18L, 53L, 
48L, 54L, 36L, 62L, 33L, 15L, 16L, 59L, 15L, 37L, 33L, 61L, 17L, 
17L, 57L, 54L, 22L, 56L, 42L, 22L, 27L, 15L, 27L, 64L, 31L, 40L, 
68L, 25L, 54L, 55L, 34L, 50L, 39L, 23L, 67L, 38L, 44L, 52L, 20L, 
21L, 18L, 45L, 50L, 15L, 48L, 24L, 25L, 10L, 32L, 67L, 28L, 41L, 
61L, 58L, 36L, 63L, 27L, 65L, 64L, 30L, 51L, 25L, 42L, 34L, 49L, 
44L, 38L, 47L, 33L, 46L, 62L, 46L, 45L, 46L, 12L, 27L, 21L, 22L, 
17L, 12L, 49L, 55L, 39L, 37L, 37L, 59L, 35L, 18L, 11L, 48L, 32L, 
4L, 25L, 42L, 42L, 52L, 36L, 74L, 51L, 35L, 66L, 36L, 60L, 31L, 
44L, 58L, 10L, 22L, 53L, 49L, 51L, 38L, 42L, 41L, 25L, 50L, 49L, 
39L, 51L, 35L, 60L, 30L, 51L, 54L, 50L, 51L, 54L, 13L, 34L, 34L, 
54L, 26L, 26L, 43L, 20L, 30L, 35L, 43L, 33L, 4L, 46L, 36L, 35L, 
2L, 36L, 41L, 45L, 16L, 33L, 59L, 64L, 19L, 15L, 29L, 6L, 57L, 
50L, 59L, 52L, 24L, 49L, 9L, 44L, 39L, 56L, 31L, 50L, 50L, 29L, 
11L, 69L, 29L, 40L, 50L, 15L, 55L, 31L, 58L, 13L, 36L, 18L, 21L, 
46L, 27L, 58L, 75L, 28L, 22L, 61L, 2L, 46L, 27L, 23L, 48L, 54L, 
34L, 44L, 50L, 40L, 18L, 27L, 28L, 40L, 35L, 50L, 39L, 34L, 51L, 
28L, 39L, 30L, 65L, 5L, 12L, 27L, 48L, 38L, 54L, 41L, 37L, 31L, 
41L, 35L, 1L, 59L, 65L, 49L, 60L, 1L, 46L, 7L, 55L, 42L, 18L, 
11L, 32L, 31L, 50L, 52L, 50L, 43L, 45L, 36L, 35L, 10L, 24L, 53L, 
19L, 43L, 40L, 38L, 28L, 27L, 46L, 55L, 29L, 37L, 53L, 53L, 55L, 
39L, 38L, 46L, 25L, 11L, 17L, 42L, 31L, 33L, 17L, 8L, 15L, 39L, 
39L, 47L, 25L, 46L, 37L, 37L, 40L, 62L, 42L, 25L, 21L, 30L, 18L, 
54L, 8L, 20L, 32L, 38L, 41L, 16L, 19L, 75L, 19L, 38L, 63L, 23L, 
49L, 22L, 32L, 35L, 62L, 38L, 36L, 31L, 31L, 23L, 24L, 52L, 25L, 
27L, 36L, 39L, 11L, 16L, 45L, 61L, 8L, 38L, 50L, 18L, 52L, 4L, 
53L, 24L, 13L, 34L, 39L, 47L, 59L, 22L, 39L, 9L, 29L, 20L, 73L, 
55L, 71L, 34L, 55L, 52L, 35L, 50L, 58L, 37L, 3L, 20L, 3L, 57L, 
51L, 29L, 10L, 30L, 46L, 7L, 47L, 64L, 58L, 60L, 47L, 39L, 43L, 
46L, 62L, 59L, 38L, 34L, 32L, 28L, 59L, 39L, 25L, 15L, 56L, 37L, 
12L, 48L, 51L, 43L, 59L, 19L, 10L, 50L, 42L, 19L, 39L, 58L, 24L, 
49L, 27L, 9L, 15L, 16L, 39L, 11L, 49L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 47L, 57L, 
59L, 49L, 20L, 51L, 43L, 46L, 19L, 51L, 47L, 47L, 25L, 5L, 52L, 
40L, 21L, 36L, 6L, 64L, 35L, 29L, 40L, 63L, 26L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
51L, 43L, 27L, 41L, 19L, 49L, 52L, 61L, 50L, 37L, 42L, 50L, 47L, 
41L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 37L, 52L, 27L, 60L, 29L, 22L, 37L, 38L, 15L, 
37L, 24L, 21L, 50L, 60L, 36L, 39L, 48L, 59L, 46L, 73L, 35L, 31L, 
34L, 25L, 75L, 41L, 20L, 36L, 55L, 10L, 39L, 44L, 62L, 40L, 14L, 
29L, 49L, 45L, 59L, 54L, 52L, 41L, 40L, 35L, 36L, 32L, 2L, 51L, 
24L, 49L, 22L, 49L, 57L, 28L, 12L, 35L, 5L, 31L, 7L, 6L, 51L, 
33L, 24L, 6L, 51L, 25L, 10L, 52L, 54L, 75L, 12L, 55L, 42L, 17L, 
15L, 39L, 52L, 29L, 6L, 11L, 59L, 40L, 36L, 17L, 14L, 27L, 14L, 
56L, 33L, 59L, 55L, 31L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 39L, 7L, 20L, 50L, 8L, 
2L, 31L, 59L, 39L, 71L, 24L, 32L, 8L, 60L, 24L, 21L, 37L, 17L, 
24L, 42L, 33L, 25L, 32L, 12L, 38L, 46L, 31L, 40L, 37L, 12L, 19L, 
21L, 44L, 20L, 30L, 38L, 45L, 2L, 30L, 60L, 15L, 23L, 34L, 6L, 
35L, 23L, 25L, 31L, 18L, 42L, 59L, 40L, 42L, 16L, 46L, 71L, 21L, 
36L, 18L, 37L, 38L, 31L, 65L, 34L, 55L, 59L, 34L, 66L, 29L, 31L, 
7L, 8L, 58L, 14L, 23L, 65L, 29L, 16L, 52L, 35L, 7L, 20L, 14L, 
15L, 46L, 9L, 61L, 45L, 26L, 27L, 59L, 26L, 38L, 29L, 14L, 32L, 
47L, 36L, 40L, 57L, 39L, 31L, 25L, 34L, 46L, 39L, 59L, 11L, 26L, 
21L, 9L, 13L, 47L, 37L, 43L, 45L, 19L, 52L, 42L, 53L, 26L, 49L, 
37L, 33L, 50L, 28L, 25L, 35L, 6L, 55L, 25L, 11L, 16L, 53L, 32L, 
20L, 20L, 41L, 55L, 22L, 12L, 50L, 13L, 71L, 22L, 5L, 56L, 33L, 
44L, 57L, 52L, 53L, 44L, 18L, 32L, 60L, 59L, 24L, 48L, 29L, 45L, 
16L, 53L, 55L, 13L, 41L, 6L, 72L, 30L, 22L, 31L, 32L, 8L, 41L, 
34L, 4L, 1L, 34L, 9L, 20L, 33L, 67L, 9L, 48L, 72L, 31L, 40L, 
38L, 56L, 50L, 45L, 63L, 18L, 31L, 11L, 35L, 51L, 55L, 57L, 21L, 
48L, 50L, 28L, 55L, 39L, 33L, 2L, 35L, 6L, 30L, 25L, 18L, 17L, 
30L, 40L, 38L, 31L, 46L, 69L, 36L, 14L, 35L, 42L, 32L, 66L, 55L, 
25L, 13L, 76L, 54L, 57L, 24L, 17L, 24L, 35L, 32L, 27L, 56L, 5L, 
54L, 30L, 53L, 62L, 41L, 38L, 30L, 2L, 69L, 35L, 46L, 44L, 36L, 
33L, 30L, 57L, 61L, 42L, 63L, 30L, 44L, 34L, 17L, 53L, 53L, 15L, 
46L, 58L, 43L, 21L, 36L, 27L, 21L, 32L, 28L, 10L, 15L, 8L, 53L, 
63L, 43L, 10L, 64L, 41L, 58L, 7L, 36L, 26L, 19L, 26L, 52L, 14L, 
36L, 4L, 49L, 20L, 42L, 35L, 9L, 23L, 57L, 5L, 43L, 40L, 31L, 
26L, 49L, 31L, 41L, 3L, 13L, 45L, 29L, 42L, 41L, 57L, 67L, 37L, 
50L, 25L, 47L, 25L, 52L, 60L, 38L, 49L, 40L, 43L, 45L, 45L, 42L, 
50L, 63L, 10L, 42L, 31L, 26L, 26L, 60L, 54L, 9L, 3L, 57L, 63L, 
44L, 45L, 31L, 61L, 48L, 3L, 55L, 41L, 40L, 32L, 22L, 23L, 37L, 
39L, 30L, 6L, 25L, 2L, 41L, 3L, 15L, 35L, 50L, 48L, 17L, 30L, 
55L, 40L, 24L, 39L, 47L, 49L, 48L, 16L, 14L, 5L, 31L, 29L, 32L, 
60L, 34L, 55L, 58L, 51L, 30L, 48L, 47L, 52L, 30L, 35L, 65L, 7L, 
54L, 9L, 23L, 59L, 25L, 19L, 47L, 38L, 56L, 73L, 70L, 47L, 64L, 
43L, 30L, 40L, 45L, 3L, 40L, 35L, 50L, 10L, 35L, 49L, 33L, 28L, 
8L, 6L, 60L, 37L, 46L, 65L, 48L, 47L, 27L, 23L, 13L, 39L, 40L, 
44L, 55L, 35L, 21L, 21L, 51L, 33L, 49L, 11L, 25L, 25L, 44L, 6L, 
25L, 30L, 22L, 45L, 31L, 23L, 56L, 37L, 47L, 20L, 25L, 48L, 23L, 
58L, 47L, 46L, 45L, 31L, 28L, 13L, 68L, 18L, 42L, 22L, 33L, 33L, 
11L, 47L, 50L, 21L, 2L, 22L, 48L, 38L, 39L, 32L, 29L, 52L, 10L, 
35L, 45L, 43L, 2L, 41L, 23L, 3L, 41L, 29L, 39L, 44L, 11L, 44L, 
68L, 36L, 27L, 27L, 54L, 44L, 39L, 58L, 24L, 19L, 57L, 22L, 16L, 
64L, 25L, 3L, 60L, 51L, 46L, 50L, 32L, 6L, 52L, 43L, 59L, 36L, 
36L, 7L, 14L, 49L, 22L, 69L, 40L, 51L, 56L, 44L, 10L, 30L, 46L, 
53L, 30L, 17L, 32L, 37L, 36L, 9L, 41L, 2L, 34L, 57L, 27L, 25L, 
25L, 55L, 48L, 40L, 36L, 25L, 36L, 7L, 41L, 44L, 22L, 55L, 38L, 
31L, 49L, 62L, 15L, 48L, 13L, 23L, 20L, 48L, 21L, 50L, 33L, 23L, 
67L, 30L, 39L, 34L, 41L, 32L, 43L, 43L, 26L, 24L, 27L, 10L, 20L, 
77L, 22L, 56L, 54L, 67L, 52L, 14L, 38L, 24L, 50L, 33L, 39L, 40L, 
67L, 33L, 44L, 51L, 72L, 39L, 47L, 9L, 43L, 54L, 5L, 35L, 52L, 
16L, 37L, 45L, 22L, 27L, 35L, 61L, 51L, 2L, 59L, 49L, 45L, 22L, 
44L, 31L, 49L, 35L, 22L, 35L, 35L, 44L, 48L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 59L, 
27L, 47L, 25L, 28L, 8L, 40L, 37L, 50L, 75L, 16L, 39L, 42L, 52L, 
31L, 36L, 43L, 19L, 66L, 21L, 22L, 64L, 38L, 26L, 43L, 64L, 56L, 
1L, 3L, 27L, 28L, 10L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 30L, 38L, 39L, 57L, 24L, 
55L, 23L, 42L, 35L, 5L, 53L, 71L, 40L, 12L, 37L, 37L, 8L, 7L, 
24L, 37L, 31L, 59L, 44L, 50L, 50L, 63L, 42L, 24L, 61L, 2L, 56L, 
36L, 48L, 41L, 27L, 10L, 16L, 71L, 33L, 24L, 40L, 16L, 45L, 64L, 
45L, 59L, 12L, 26L, 42L, 54L, 52L, 37L, 53L, 43L, 47L, 8L, 51L, 
43L, 59L, 14L, 44L, 48L, 3L, 51L, 27L, 3L, 48L, 57L, 31L, 23L, 
17L, 52L, 11L, 62L, 39L, 40L, 57L, 43L, 53L, 38L, 31L, 14L, 53L, 
43L, 39L, 20L, 56L, 31L, 11L, 37L, 31L, 49L, 36L, 35L, 50L, 19L, 
47L, 28L, 53L, 30L, 17L, 27L, 35L, 48L, 34L, 32L, 36L, 23L, 17L, 
14L, 24L, 56L, 28L, 58L, 40L, 48L, 32L, 28L, 32L, 21L, 24L, 43L, 
44L, 67L, 18L, 63L, 30L, 31L, 29L, 57L, 44L, 35L, 40L, 30L, 32L, 
16L, 45L, 27L, 36L, 28L, 23L, 38L, 35L, 30L, 43L, 59L, 57L, 50L, 
23L, 16L, 64L, 44L, 50L, 43L, 40L, 21L, 41L, 59L, 22L, 32L, 15L, 
22L, 49L, 60L, 29L, 44L, 58L, 40L, 24L, 23L, 34L, 25L, 41L, 14L, 
16L, 32L, 37L, 51L, 45L, 54L, 40L, 43L, 24L, 56L, 67L, 47L, 48L, 
41L, 47L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 57L, 66L, 47L, 4L, 32L, 48L, 26L, 2L, 
24L, 40L, 43L, 30L, 34L, 30L, 29L, 53L, 22L, 19L, 31L, 58L, 3L, 
18L, 30L, 31L, 35L, 64L, 59L, 17L, 4L, 42L, 32L, 75L, 31L, 13L, 
59L, 12L, 31L, 49L, 34L, 13L, 30L, 1L, 16L, 34L, 35L, 17L, 19L, 
50L, 52L, 25L, 33L, 50L, 10L, 23L, 22L, 47L, 43L, 54L, 5L, 41L, 
28L, 13L, 46L, 44L, 9L, 24L, 22L, 33L, 58L, 17L, 59L, 29L, 44L, 
34L, 10L, 30L, 24L, 15L, 40L, 42L, 5L, 39L, 34L, 28L, 6L, 40L, 
44L, 25L, 50L, 57L, 40L, 53L, 37L, 41L, 48L, 48L, 23L, 55L, 20L, 
8L, 41L, 46L, 27L, 39L, 51L, 20L, 36L, 45L, 33L, 71L, 3L, 15L, 
49L, 21L, 34L, 5L, 42L, 2L, 40L, 35L, 13L, 13L, 2L, 42L, 17L, 
7L, 53L, 30L, 27L, 11L, 37L, 49L, 23L, 45L, 32L, 30L, 16L, 21L, 
32L, 20L, 40L, 29L, 3L, 46L, 34L, 56L, 46L, 21L, 46L, 25L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 53L, 31L, 27L, 34L, 67L, 29L, 62L, 37L, 51L, 36L, 32L, 
10L, 50L, 44L, 43L, 40L, 34L, 26L, 62L, 24L, 63L, 50L, 13L, 42L, 
43L, 49L, 29L, 30L, 9L, 40L, 11L, 61L, 67L, 37L, 20L, 49L, 66L, 
49L, 34L, 25L, 30L, 58L, 45L, 15L, 18L, 32L, 29L, 17L, 18L, 43L, 
72L, 54L, 40L, 29L, 18L, 39L, 35L, 16L, 37L, 18L, 1L, 43L, 22L, 
38L, 57L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 46L, 25L, 15L, 36L, 26L, 32L, 15L, 57L, 
33L, 25L, 63L, 35L, 44L, 25L, 13L, 26L, 56L, 30L, 39L, 35L, 39L, 
20L, 47L, 44L, 22L, 45L, 23L, 7L, 30L, 47L, 7L, 54L, 47L, 5L, 
52L, 21L, 72L, 23L, 41L, 43L, 30L, 28L, 32L, 43L, 35L, 66L, 70L, 
37L, 44L, 33L, 11L, 51L, 26L, 48L, 41L, 10L, 50L, 31L, 39L, 41L, 
43L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 17L, 47L, 25L, 48L, 15L, 49L, 50L, 34L, 16L, 
26L, 32L, 27L, 71L, 41L, 30L, 34L, 36L, 47L, 32L, 17L, 19L, 33L, 
26L, 17L, 25L, 22L, 35L, 42L, 25L, 37L, 6L, 46L, 3L, 53L, 39L, 
29L, 10L, 41L, 45L, 10L, 31L, 43L, 35L, 43L, 30L, 6L, 12L, 28L, 
18L, 40L, 35L, 37L, 23L, 29L, 8L, 32L, 55L, 53L, 12L, 16L, 35L, 
23L, 27L, 51L, 32L, 36L, 9L, 43L, 26L, 28L, 36L, 46L, 56L, 21L, 
21L, 19L, 16L, 21L, 16L, 8L, 12L, 44L, 4L, 21L, 26L, 66L, 64L, 
9L, 38L, 34L, 50L, 20L, 36L, 37L, 31L, 55L, 37L, 60L, 20L, 61L, 
28L, 65L, 44L, 33L, 50L, 53L, 34L, 43L, 27L, 17L, 30L, 55L, 20L, 
43L, 46L, 50L, 44L, 27L, 44L, 43L, 23L, 26L, 52L, 23L, 52L, 27L, 
40L, 17L, 50L, 8L, 21L, 36L, 68L, 19L, 26L, 45L, 47L, 30L, 27L, 
42L, 22L, 38L, 36L, 16L, 15L, 27L, 47L, 26L, 51L, 17L, 54L, 60L, 
38L, 23L, 19L, 30L, 44L, 42L, 7L, 33L, 56L, 14L, 45L, 54L, 47L, 
64L, 64L, 18L, 55L, 67L, 36L, 51L, 30L, 12L, 59L, 33L, 12L, 33L, 
17L, 13L, 44L, 24L, 46L, 41L, 25L, 41L, 33L, 27L, 1L, 14L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 8L, 48L, 22L, 39L, 59L, 36L, 34L, 37L, 13L, 38L, 32L, 
22L, 3L, 30L, 21L, 51L, 38L, 4L, 8L, 50L, 38L, 30L, 31L, 22L, 
37L, 62L, 46L, 45L, 26L, 13L, 51L, 54L, 38L, 13L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 
22L, 33L, 24L, 22L, 52L, 26L, 11L, 46L, 18L, 27L, 32L, 56L, 2L, 
36L, 13L, 71L, 56L, 43L, 37L, 5L, 63L, 34L, 51L, 34L, 38L, 29L, 
35L, 44L, 68L, 18L, 30L, 41L, 50L, 58L, 48L, 43L, 16L, 33L, 43L, 
46L, 61L, 29L, 46L, 73L, 8L, 21L, 19L, 12L, 35L, 25L, 21L, 34L, 
44L, 52L, 3L, 36L, 5L, 51L, 9L, 50L, 60L, 24L, 3L, 31L, 13L, 
36L, 42L, 67L, 44L, 18L, 8L, 20L, 60L, 38L, 69L, 65L, 23L, 44L, 
52L, 45L, 29L, 51L, 22L, 23L, 27L, 58L, 61L, 32L, 33L, 58L, 31L, 
30L, 50L, 64L, 24L, 4L, 45L, 43L, 46L, 53L, 35L, 51L, 51L, 45L, 
37L, 30L, 2L, 58L, 41L, 35L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 33L, 60L, 60L, 55L, 
37L, 27L, 10L, 21L, 27L, 17L, 33L, 46L, 28L, 36L, 53L, 34L, 26L, 
36L, 59L, 9L, 30L, 55L, 45L, 57L, 17L, 19L, 2L, 31L, 41L, 26L, 
29L, 16L, 47L, 52L, 44L, 29L, 61L, 25L, 55L, 8L, 5L, 56L, 45L, 
51L, 25L, 11L, 26L, 35L, 33L, 41L, 71L, 35L, 63L, 38L, 32L, 53L, 
31L, 52L, 44L, 34L, 50L, 40L, 21L, 36L, 76L, 40L, 23L, 42L, 25L, 
14L, 58L, 38L, 37L, 69L, 46L, 46L, 49L, 42L, 28L, 55L, 13L, 45L, 
12L, 42L, 32L, 11L, 32L, 36L, 61L, 19L, 28L, 31L, 35L, 22L, 15L, 
50L, 64L, 32L, 59L, 33L, 24L, 19L, 49L, 36L, 26L, 57L, 57L, 34L, 
29L, 7L, 30L, 42L, 47L, 53L, 55L, 55L, 35L, 26L, 20L, 55L, 61L, 
43L, 31L, 30L, 52L, 27L, 63L, 25L, 47L, 63L, 23L, 2L, 47L, 12L, 
37L, 34L, 46L, 30L, 62L, 52L, 27L, 3L, 59L, 50L, 5L, 34L, 23L
), levels = c("16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", 
"46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", 
"57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
"68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", 
"79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", 
"90", "91", "93", "N.C.   "), class = "factor"), CIS.P3 = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), levels = c("Mejor", "(NO LEER) Igual", "Peor", "N.S.", 
"N.C."), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2787L))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Also before asking a new question, please take the time to thank the responders of your previous questions by accepting their answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Dear Dave2e, I'm always highly appreciative and give thanks to the members of community who respond my questions. If I do not accept their answers yet, it is because my knowledge of R is, as of now, rather limited. It is certainly something that I will do in the future, once I get a better grasp of R.

Comment: You could please share some reproducible data using `dput(CIS)`?

Comment: Hello, @Quinten! Unfortunately, CIS is an extremely large dataset (my RStudio has collapsed when trying to run ```dput(CIS)```but I've shared the data of ```CIS_data_5```. I hope this gives and idea and serves! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this using `facet_wrap`:

```r
set.seed(123)

CIS_data_5 <- data.frame(
  CIS$CIS.P20,
  CIS$CIS.P3
)

CIS$P3 <- factor(CIS$CIS.P3, labels = c("Mejor", "(NO LEER) Igual", "Peor", "N.S.", "N.C."))

n <- as.numeric(c(CIS$CIS.P20))
P20 <- sample(n, 2787, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)

P20labs <- c("16-29", "30-44", "45-64", ">65", "N.C.")
cut_points <- c(16, 30, 45, 65, Inf)

i <- findInterval(P20, cut_points)
P20_fac <- P20labs[i]
P20_fac[is.na(P20)] <- P20labs[length(P20labs)]
P20_fac <- factor(P20_fac, levels = P20labs)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data.frame(P3 = CIS$P3,
           P20_fac = P20_fac) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = P20_fac)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~P3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, @Quinten! This is an absolutely fenomenal solution to my problem! Thank you once again!

Comment: Actually, I am sorry, @Quinten! I've been revising the code and I've realised that it is impossible that, say, for the age interval of "30-44", their answers are the most salient in all 3/5 categories ("Mejor", "(NO LEER) Igual", and "Peor"). Translating from Spanish, the name of the categories are 'Better', 'Same' and 'Worse', respectively. Therefore, if they are 'better' in the 1st category, there should be a lower number of answers 'worse' in the 3rd one. Do you know, by chance, what is wrong in my code, so that I get such results? I hope I have expressed myself clear enough. Many thanks!