# Error in my code, gives incongruent results (R)

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
#Analysis of Question 3 (current versus past situation of Spanish consumers, their perception of their own situation) in addition to Question 20 (facet of the respondents' age)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

CIS_data_5 <- data.frame(
  CIS$P20,
  CIS$P3
)

CIS$P3 <- factor(CIS$P3, labels = c("Mejor", "Igual", "Peor", "N.S.", "N.C."))

n <- as.numeric(c(CIS$P20))
P20 <- sample(n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)

P20labs <- c("16-29", "30-44", "45-64", ">65", "N.C.")
cut_points <- c(16, 30, 45, 65, Inf)

i <- findInterval(P20, cut_points)
P20_fac <- P20labs[i]
P20_fac[is.na(P20)] <- P20labs[length(P20labs)]
P20_fac <- factor(P20_fac, levels = P20labs)

data.frame(P3 = CIS$P3,
           P20_fac = P20_fac) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = P20_fac)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~P3) +
  xlab("Current VS Past Individual Situation Based on Age") +
  ylab("Count")
```

`dput(CIS_data_5)` is as follows:

```
structure(list(CIS.P20 = structure(c(48L, 33L, 28L, 36L, 32L, 
24L, 27L, 50L, 55L, 34L, 48L, 22L, 37L, 24L, 35L, 35L, 19L, 57L, 
32L, 45L, 13L, 23L, 24L, 5L, 8L, 34L, 2L, 52L, 66L, 43L, 54L, 
24L, 27L, 40L, 40L, 64L, 29L, 12L, 52L, 7L, 26L, 40L, 59L, 19L, 
24L, 44L, 19L, 62L, 26L, 16L, 40L, 31L, 14L, 15L, 29L, 24L, 41L, 
33L, 41L, 3L, 39L, 4L, 44L, 39L, 1L, 28L, 40L, 8L, 49L, 59L, 
50L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 41L, 35L, 35L, 65L, 40L, 38L, 29L, 24L, 54L, 
40L, 21L, 29L, 3L, 27L, 45L, 50L, 27L, 50L, 60L, 50L, 41L, 56L, 
57L, 33L, 45L, 31L, 58L, 3L, 16L, 43L, 25L, 40L, 32L, 17L, 58L, 
46L, 15L, 40L, 22L, 28L, 11L, 38L, 50L, 22L, 25L, 47L, 17L, 32L, 
36L, 49L, 40L, 23L, 17L, 34L, 8L, 37L, 67L, 37L, 52L, 60L, 5L, 
55L, 45L, 40L, 36L, 46L, 50L, 13L, 73L, 31L, 33L, 47L, 58L, 37L, 
55L, 16L, 38L, 32L, 15L, 45L, 33L, 9L, 47L, 10L, 9L, 33L, 41L, 
31L, 31L, 21L, 28L, 26L, 68L, 15L, 63L, 38L, 59L, 30L, 47L, 21L, 
36L, 50L, 40L, 30L, 14L, 54L, 16L, 60L, 8L, 44L, 49L, 68L, 33L, 
24L, 58L, 27L, 34L, 33L, 47L, 50L, 52L, 15L, 21L, 16L, 47L, 59L, 
37L, 34L, 11L, 37L, 50L, 9L, 41L, 51L, 31L, 35L, 26L, 5L, 24L, 
51L, 6L, 27L, 52L, 68L, 8L, 39L, 33L, 51L, 41L, 53L, 39L, 60L, 
43L, 10L, 51L, 26L, 41L, 51L, 54L, 35L, 33L, 35L, 39L, 28L, 48L, 
5L, 31L, 50L, 8L, 45L, 50L, 41L, 53L, 54L, 32L, 43L, 65L, 22L, 
32L, 24L, 35L, 40L, 34L, 41L, 19L, 48L, 46L, 35L, 24L, 12L, 35L, 
19L, 8L, 30L, 58L, 55L, 16L, 37L, 17L, 1L, 35L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 
53L, 50L, 42L, 37L, 29L, 54L, 4L, 29L, 47L, 51L, 58L, 10L, 29L, 
36L, 16L, 9L, 54L, 36L, 19L, 49L, 59L, 39L, 6L, 35L, 25L, 52L, 
3L, 47L, 52L, 51L, 26L, 65L, 23L, 35L, 45L, 55L, 45L, 9L, 19L, 
32L, 49L, 47L, 45L, 7L, 31L, 24L, 7L, 21L, 45L, 52L, 57L, 37L, 
56L, 39L, 26L, 46L, 35L, 35L, 4L, 20L, 21L, 45L, 23L, 20L, 41L, 
23L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 60L, 43L, 27L, 56L, 38L, 44L, 35L, 14L, 58L, 
50L, 29L, 25L, 15L, 10L, 57L, 61L, 46L, 43L, 23L, 29L, 57L, 24L, 
32L, 36L, 33L, 34L, 31L, 60L, 4L, 42L, 43L, 41L, 51L, 29L, 10L, 
29L, 48L, 29L, 37L, 62L, 17L, 37L, 45L, 17L, 47L, 53L, 10L, 35L, 
8L, 25L, 32L, 51L, 46L, 39L, 46L, 48L, 4L, 35L, 34L, 37L, 3L, 
6L, 74L, 13L, 60L, 36L, 1L, 33L, 13L, 23L, 42L, 60L, 39L, 66L, 
49L, 50L, 57L, 41L, 16L, 23L, 28L, 6L, 45L, 53L, 21L, 26L, 40L, 
21L, 34L, 37L, 6L, 50L, 48L, 28L, 62L, 50L, 48L, 28L, 14L, 31L, 
44L, 17L, 26L, 46L, 17L, 11L, 55L, 24L, 33L, 30L, 52L, 22L, 40L, 
43L, 29L, 36L, 60L, 5L, 45L, 33L, 44L, 35L, 32L, 19L, 51L, 19L, 
29L, 24L, 35L, 28L, 42L, 6L, 42L, 63L, 19L, 11L, 56L, 48L, 8L, 
12L, 30L, 12L, 48L, 56L, 20L, 54L, 32L, 64L, 42L, 44L, 28L, 26L, 
42L, 48L, 33L, 46L, 46L, 23L, 28L, 64L, 25L, 19L, 26L, 3L, 31L, 
49L, 40L, 65L, 28L, 20L, 47L, 24L, 71L, 13L, 34L, 48L, 27L, 43L, 
1L, 28L, 56L, 24L, 25L, 29L, 43L, 54L, 55L, 29L, 38L, 56L, 27L, 
72L, 47L, 25L, 34L, 23L, 15L, 37L, 18L, 55L, 49L, 39L, 32L, 54L, 
14L, 34L, 14L, 21L, 3L, 56L, 24L, 32L, 38L, 50L, 68L, 44L, 12L, 
30L, 29L, 58L, 31L, 51L, 33L, 38L, 48L, 27L, 55L, 62L, 12L, 29L, 
71L, 38L, 61L, 48L, 45L, 55L, 23L, 58L, 37L, 55L, 5L, 51L, 20L, 
10L, 30L, 60L, 39L, 40L, 21L, 44L, 16L, 25L, 15L, 47L, 18L, 53L, 
48L, 54L, 36L, 62L, 33L, 15L, 16L, 59L, 15L, 37L, 33L, 61L, 17L, 
17L, 57L, 54L, 22L, 56L, 42L, 22L, 27L, 15L, 27L, 64L, 31L, 40L, 
68L, 25L, 54L, 55L, 34L, 50L, 39L, 23L, 67L, 38L, 44L, 52L, 20L, 
21L, 18L, 45L, 50L, 15L, 48L, 24L, 25L, 10L, 32L, 67L, 28L, 41L, 
61L, 58L, 36L, 63L, 27L, 65L, 64L, 30L, 51L, 25L, 42L, 34L, 49L, 
44L, 38L, 47L, 33L, 46L, 62L, 46L, 45L, 46L, 12L, 27L, 21L, 22L, 
17L, 12L, 49L, 55L, 39L, 37L, 37L, 59L, 35L, 18L, 11L, 48L, 32L, 
4L, 25L, 42L, 42L, 52L, 36L, 74L, 51L, 35L, 66L, 36L, 60L, 31L, 
44L, 58L, 10L, 22L, 53L, 49L, 51L, 38L, 42L, 41L, 25L, 50L, 49L, 
39L, 51L, 35L, 60L, 30L, 51L, 54L, 50L, 51L, 54L, 13L, 34L, 34L, 
54L, 26L, 26L, 43L, 20L, 30L, 35L, 43L, 33L, 4L, 46L, 36L, 35L, 
2L, 36L, 41L, 45L, 16L, 33L, 59L, 64L, 19L, 15L, 29L, 6L, 57L, 
50L, 59L, 52L, 24L, 49L, 9L, 44L, 39L, 56L, 31L, 50L, 50L, 29L, 
11L, 69L, 29L, 40L, 50L, 15L, 55L, 31L, 58L, 13L, 36L, 18L, 21L, 
46L, 27L, 58L, 75L, 28L, 22L, 61L, 2L, 46L, 27L, 23L, 48L, 54L, 
34L, 44L, 50L, 40L, 18L, 27L, 28L, 40L, 35L, 50L, 39L, 34L, 51L, 
28L, 39L, 30L, 65L, 5L, 12L, 27L, 48L, 38L, 54L, 41L, 37L, 31L, 
41L, 35L, 1L, 59L, 65L, 49L, 60L, 1L, 46L, 7L, 55L, 42L, 18L, 
11L, 32L, 31L, 50L, 52L, 50L, 43L, 45L, 36L, 35L, 10L, 24L, 53L, 
19L, 43L, 40L, 38L, 28L, 27L, 46L, 55L, 29L, 37L, 53L, 53L, 55L, 
39L, 38L, 46L, 25L, 11L, 17L, 42L, 31L, 33L, 17L, 8L, 15L, 39L, 
39L, 47L, 25L, 46L, 37L, 37L, 40L, 62L, 42L, 25L, 21L, 30L, 18L, 
54L, 8L, 20L, 32L, 38L, 41L, 16L, 19L, 75L, 19L, 38L, 63L, 23L, 
49L, 22L, 32L, 35L, 62L, 38L, 36L, 31L, 31L, 23L, 24L, 52L, 25L, 
27L, 36L, 39L, 11L, 16L, 45L, 61L, 8L, 38L, 50L, 18L, 52L, 4L, 
53L, 24L, 13L, 34L, 39L, 47L, 59L, 22L, 39L, 9L, 29L, 20L, 73L, 
55L, 71L, 34L, 55L, 52L, 35L, 50L, 58L, 37L, 3L, 20L, 3L, 57L, 
51L, 29L, 10L, 30L, 46L, 7L, 47L, 64L, 58L, 60L, 47L, 39L, 43L, 
46L, 62L, 59L, 38L, 34L, 32L, 28L, 59L, 39L, 25L, 15L, 56L, 37L, 
12L, 48L, 51L, 43L, 59L, 19L, 10L, 50L, 42L, 19L, 39L, 58L, 24L, 
49L, 27L, 9L, 15L, 16L, 39L, 11L, 49L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 47L, 57L, 
59L, 49L, 20L, 51L, 43L, 46L, 19L, 51L, 47L, 47L, 25L, 5L, 52L, 
40L, 21L, 36L, 6L, 64L, 35L, 29L, 40L, 63L, 26L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
51L, 43L, 27L, 41L, 19L, 49L, 52L, 61L, 50L, 37L, 42L, 50L, 47L, 
41L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 37L, 52L, 27L, 60L, 29L, 22L, 37L, 38L, 15L, 
37L, 24L, 21L, 50L, 60L, 36L, 39L, 48L, 59L, 46L, 73L, 35L, 31L, 
34L, 25L, 75L, 41L, 20L, 36L, 55L, 10L, 39L, 44L, 62L, 40L, 14L, 
29L, 49L, 45L, 59L, 54L, 52L, 41L, 40L, 35L, 36L, 32L, 2L, 51L, 
24L, 49L, 22L, 49L, 57L, 28L, 12L, 35L, 5L, 31L, 7L, 6L, 51L, 
33L, 24L, 6L, 51L, 25L, 10L, 52L, 54L, 75L, 12L, 55L, 42L, 17L, 
15L, 39L, 52L, 29L, 6L, 11L, 59L, 40L, 36L, 17L, 14L, 27L, 14L, 
56L, 33L, 59L, 55L, 31L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 39L, 7L, 20L, 50L, 8L, 
2L, 31L, 59L, 39L, 71L, 24L, 32L, 8L, 60L, 24L, 21L, 37L, 17L, 
24L, 42L, 33L, 25L, 32L, 12L, 38L, 46L, 31L, 40L, 37L, 12L, 19L, 
21L, 44L, 20L, 30L, 38L, 45L, 2L, 30L, 60L, 15L, 23L, 34L, 6L, 
35L, 23L, 25L, 31L, 18L, 42L, 59L, 40L, 42L, 16L, 46L, 71L, 21L, 
36L, 18L, 37L, 38L, 31L, 65L, 34L, 55L, 59L, 34L, 66L, 29L, 31L, 
7L, 8L, 58L, 14L, 23L, 65L, 29L, 16L, 52L, 35L, 7L, 20L, 14L, 
15L, 46L, 9L, 61L, 45L, 26L, 27L, 59L, 26L, 38L, 29L, 14L, 32L, 
47L, 36L, 40L, 57L, 39L, 31L, 25L, 34L, 46L, 39L, 59L, 11L, 26L, 
21L, 9L, 13L, 47L, 37L, 43L, 45L, 19L, 52L, 42L, 53L, 26L, 49L, 
37L, 33L, 50L, 28L, 25L, 35L, 6L, 55L, 25L, 11L, 16L, 53L, 32L, 
20L, 20L, 41L, 55L, 22L, 12L, 50L, 13L, 71L, 22L, 5L, 56L, 33L, 
44L, 57L, 52L, 53L, 44L, 18L, 32L, 60L, 59L, 24L, 48L, 29L, 45L, 
16L, 53L, 55L, 13L, 41L, 6L, 72L, 30L, 22L, 31L, 32L, 8L, 41L, 
34L, 4L, 1L, 34L, 9L, 20L, 33L, 67L, 9L, 48L, 72L, 31L, 40L, 
38L, 56L, 50L, 45L, 63L, 18L, 31L, 11L, 35L, 51L, 55L, 57L, 21L, 
48L, 50L, 28L, 55L, 39L, 33L, 2L, 35L, 6L, 30L, 25L, 18L, 17L, 
30L, 40L, 38L, 31L, 46L, 69L, 36L, 14L, 35L, 42L, 32L, 66L, 55L, 
25L, 13L, 76L, 54L, 57L, 24L, 17L, 24L, 35L, 32L, 27L, 56L, 5L, 
54L, 30L, 53L, 62L, 41L, 38L, 30L, 2L, 69L, 35L, 46L, 44L, 36L, 
33L, 30L, 57L, 61L, 42L, 63L, 30L, 44L, 34L, 17L, 53L, 53L, 15L, 
46L, 58L, 43L, 21L, 36L, 27L, 21L, 32L, 28L, 10L, 15L, 8L, 53L, 
63L, 43L, 10L, 64L, 41L, 58L, 7L, 36L, 26L, 19L, 26L, 52L, 14L, 
36L, 4L, 49L, 20L, 42L, 35L, 9L, 23L, 57L, 5L, 43L, 40L, 31L, 
26L, 49L, 31L, 41L, 3L, 13L, 45L, 29L, 42L, 41L, 57L, 67L, 37L, 
50L, 25L, 47L, 25L, 52L, 60L, 38L, 49L, 40L, 43L, 45L, 45L, 42L, 
50L, 63L, 10L, 42L, 31L, 26L, 26L, 60L, 54L, 9L, 3L, 57L, 63L, 
44L, 45L, 31L, 61L, 48L, 3L, 55L, 41L, 40L, 32L, 22L, 23L, 37L, 
39L, 30L, 6L, 25L, 2L, 41L, 3L, 15L, 35L, 50L, 48L, 17L, 30L, 
55L, 40L, 24L, 39L, 47L, 49L, 48L, 16L, 14L, 5L, 31L, 29L, 32L, 
60L, 34L, 55L, 58L, 51L, 30L, 48L, 47L, 52L, 30L, 35L, 65L, 7L, 
54L, 9L, 23L, 59L, 25L, 19L, 47L, 38L, 56L, 73L, 70L, 47L, 64L, 
43L, 30L, 40L, 45L, 3L, 40L, 35L, 50L, 10L, 35L, 49L, 33L, 28L, 
8L, 6L, 60L, 37L, 46L, 65L, 48L, 47L, 27L, 23L, 13L, 39L, 40L, 
44L, 55L, 35L, 21L, 21L, 51L, 33L, 49L, 11L, 25L, 25L, 44L, 6L, 
25L, 30L, 22L, 45L, 31L, 23L, 56L, 37L, 47L, 20L, 25L, 48L, 23L, 
58L, 47L, 46L, 45L, 31L, 28L, 13L, 68L, 18L, 42L, 22L, 33L, 33L, 
11L, 47L, 50L, 21L, 2L, 22L, 48L, 38L, 39L, 32L, 29L, 52L, 10L, 
35L, 45L, 43L, 2L, 41L, 23L, 3L, 41L, 29L, 39L, 44L, 11L, 44L, 
68L, 36L, 27L, 27L, 54L, 44L, 39L, 58L, 24L, 19L, 57L, 22L, 16L, 
64L, 25L, 3L, 60L, 51L, 46L, 50L, 32L, 6L, 52L, 43L, 59L, 36L, 
36L, 7L, 14L, 49L, 22L, 69L, 40L, 51L, 56L, 44L, 10L, 30L, 46L, 
53L, 30L, 17L, 32L, 37L, 36L, 9L, 41L, 2L, 34L, 57L, 27L, 25L, 
25L, 55L, 48L, 40L, 36L, 25L, 36L, 7L, 41L, 44L, 22L, 55L, 38L, 
31L, 49L, 62L, 15L, 48L, 13L, 23L, 20L, 48L, 21L, 50L, 33L, 23L, 
67L, 30L, 39L, 34L, 41L, 32L, 43L, 43L, 26L, 24L, 27L, 10L, 20L, 
77L, 22L, 56L, 54L, 67L, 52L, 14L, 38L, 24L, 50L, 33L, 39L, 40L, 
67L, 33L, 44L, 51L, 72L, 39L, 47L, 9L, 43L, 54L, 5L, 35L, 52L, 
16L, 37L, 45L, 22L, 27L, 35L, 61L, 51L, 2L, 59L, 49L, 45L, 22L, 
44L, 31L, 49L, 35L, 22L, 35L, 35L, 44L, 48L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 59L, 
27L, 47L, 25L, 28L, 8L, 40L, 37L, 50L, 75L, 16L, 39L, 42L, 52L, 
31L, 36L, 43L, 19L, 66L, 21L, 22L, 64L, 38L, 26L, 43L, 64L, 56L, 
1L, 3L, 27L, 28L, 10L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 30L, 38L, 39L, 57L, 24L, 
55L, 23L, 42L, 35L, 5L, 53L, 71L, 40L, 12L, 37L, 37L, 8L, 7L, 
24L, 37L, 31L, 59L, 44L, 50L, 50L, 63L, 42L, 24L, 61L, 2L, 56L, 
36L, 48L, 41L, 27L, 10L, 16L, 71L, 33L, 24L, 40L, 16L, 45L, 64L, 
45L, 59L, 12L, 26L, 42L, 54L, 52L, 37L, 53L, 43L, 47L, 8L, 51L, 
43L, 59L, 14L, 44L, 48L, 3L, 51L, 27L, 3L, 48L, 57L, 31L, 23L, 
17L, 52L, 11L, 62L, 39L, 40L, 57L, 43L, 53L, 38L, 31L, 14L, 53L, 
43L, 39L, 20L, 56L, 31L, 11L, 37L, 31L, 49L, 36L, 35L, 50L, 19L, 
47L, 28L, 53L, 30L, 17L, 27L, 35L, 48L, 34L, 32L, 36L, 23L, 17L, 
14L, 24L, 56L, 28L, 58L, 40L, 48L, 32L, 28L, 32L, 21L, 24L, 43L, 
44L, 67L, 18L, 63L, 30L, 31L, 29L, 57L, 44L, 35L, 40L, 30L, 32L, 
16L, 45L, 27L, 36L, 28L, 23L, 38L, 35L, 30L, 43L, 59L, 57L, 50L, 
23L, 16L, 64L, 44L, 50L, 43L, 40L, 21L, 41L, 59L, 22L, 32L, 15L, 
22L, 49L, 60L, 29L, 44L, 58L, 40L, 24L, 23L, 34L, 25L, 41L, 14L, 
16L, 32L, 37L, 51L, 45L, 54L, 40L, 43L, 24L, 56L, 67L, 47L, 48L, 
41L, 47L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 57L, 66L, 47L, 4L, 32L, 48L, 26L, 2L, 
24L, 40L, 43L, 30L, 34L, 30L, 29L, 53L, 22L, 19L, 31L, 58L, 3L, 
18L, 30L, 31L, 35L, 64L, 59L, 17L, 4L, 42L, 32L, 75L, 31L, 13L, 
59L, 12L, 31L, 49L, 34L, 13L, 30L, 1L, 16L, 34L, 35L, 17L, 19L, 
50L, 52L, 25L, 33L, 50L, 10L, 23L, 22L, 47L, 43L, 54L, 5L, 41L, 
28L, 13L, 46L, 44L, 9L, 24L, 22L, 33L, 58L, 17L, 59L, 29L, 44L, 
34L, 10L, 30L, 24L, 15L, 40L, 42L, 5L, 39L, 34L, 28L, 6L, 40L, 
44L, 25L, 50L, 57L, 40L, 53L, 37L, 41L, 48L, 48L, 23L, 55L, 20L, 
8L, 41L, 46L, 27L, 39L, 51L, 20L, 36L, 45L, 33L, 71L, 3L, 15L, 
49L, 21L, 34L, 5L, 42L, 2L, 40L, 35L, 13L, 13L, 2L, 42L, 17L, 
7L, 53L, 30L, 27L, 11L, 37L, 49L, 23L, 45L, 32L, 30L, 16L, 21L, 
32L, 20L, 40L, 29L, 3L, 46L, 34L, 56L, 46L, 21L, 46L, 25L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 53L, 31L, 27L, 34L, 67L, 29L, 62L, 37L, 51L, 36L, 32L, 
10L, 50L, 44L, 43L, 40L, 34L, 26L, 62L, 24L, 63L, 50L, 13L, 42L, 
43L, 49L, 29L, 30L, 9L, 40L, 11L, 61L, 67L, 37L, 20L, 49L, 66L, 
49L, 34L, 25L, 30L, 58L, 45L, 15L, 18L, 32L, 29L, 17L, 18L, 43L, 
72L, 54L, 40L, 29L, 18L, 39L, 35L, 16L, 37L, 18L, 1L, 43L, 22L, 
38L, 57L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 46L, 25L, 15L, 36L, 26L, 32L, 15L, 57L, 
33L, 25L, 63L, 35L, 44L, 25L, 13L, 26L, 56L, 30L, 39L, 35L, 39L, 
20L, 47L, 44L, 22L, 45L, 23L, 7L, 30L, 47L, 7L, 54L, 47L, 5L, 
52L, 21L, 72L, 23L, 41L, 43L, 30L, 28L, 32L, 43L, 35L, 66L, 70L, 
37L, 44L, 33L, 11L, 51L, 26L, 48L, 41L, 10L, 50L, 31L, 39L, 41L, 
43L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 17L, 47L, 25L, 48L, 15L, 49L, 50L, 34L, 16L, 
26L, 32L, 27L, 71L, 41L, 30L, 34L, 36L, 47L, 32L, 17L, 19L, 33L, 
26L, 17L, 25L, 22L, 35L, 42L, 25L, 37L, 6L, 46L, 3L, 53L, 39L, 
29L, 10L, 41L, 45L, 10L, 31L, 43L, 35L, 43L, 30L, 6L, 12L, 28L, 
18L, 40L, 35L, 37L, 23L, 29L, 8L, 32L, 55L, 53L, 12L, 16L, 35L, 
23L, 27L, 51L, 32L, 36L, 9L, 43L, 26L, 28L, 36L, 46L, 56L, 21L, 
21L, 19L, 16L, 21L, 16L, 8L, 12L, 44L, 4L, 21L, 26L, 66L, 64L, 
9L, 38L, 34L, 50L, 20L, 36L, 37L, 31L, 55L, 37L, 60L, 20L, 61L, 
28L, 65L, 44L, 33L, 50L, 53L, 34L, 43L, 27L, 17L, 30L, 55L, 20L, 
43L, 46L, 50L, 44L, 27L, 44L, 43L, 23L, 26L, 52L, 23L, 52L, 27L, 
40L, 17L, 50L, 8L, 21L, 36L, 68L, 19L, 26L, 45L, 47L, 30L, 27L, 
42L, 22L, 38L, 36L, 16L, 15L, 27L, 47L, 26L, 51L, 17L, 54L, 60L, 
38L, 23L, 19L, 30L, 44L, 42L, 7L, 33L, 56L, 14L, 45L, 54L, 47L, 
64L, 64L, 18L, 55L, 67L, 36L, 51L, 30L, 12L, 59L, 33L, 12L, 33L, 
17L, 13L, 44L, 24L, 46L, 41L, 25L, 41L, 33L, 27L, 1L, 14L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 8L, 48L, 22L, 39L, 59L, 36L, 34L, 37L, 13L, 38L, 32L, 
22L, 3L, 30L, 21L, 51L, 38L, 4L, 8L, 50L, 38L, 30L, 31L, 22L, 
37L, 62L, 46L, 45L, 26L, 13L, 51L, 54L, 38L, 13L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 
22L, 33L, 24L, 22L, 52L, 26L, 11L, 46L, 18L, 27L, 32L, 56L, 2L, 
36L, 13L, 71L, 56L, 43L, 37L, 5L, 63L, 34L, 51L, 34L, 38L, 29L, 
35L, 44L, 68L, 18L, 30L, 41L, 50L, 58L, 48L, 43L, 16L, 33L, 43L, 
46L, 61L, 29L, 46L, 73L, 8L, 21L, 19L, 12L, 35L, 25L, 21L, 34L, 
44L, 52L, 3L, 36L, 5L, 51L, 9L, 50L, 60L, 24L, 3L, 31L, 13L, 
36L, 42L, 67L, 44L, 18L, 8L, 20L, 60L, 38L, 69L, 65L, 23L, 44L, 
52L, 45L, 29L, 51L, 22L, 23L, 27L, 58L, 61L, 32L, 33L, 58L, 31L, 
30L, 50L, 64L, 24L, 4L, 45L, 43L, 46L, 53L, 35L, 51L, 51L, 45L, 
37L, 30L, 2L, 58L, 41L, 35L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 33L, 60L, 60L, 55L, 
37L, 27L, 10L, 21L, 27L, 17L, 33L, 46L, 28L, 36L, 53L, 34L, 26L, 
36L, 59L, 9L, 30L, 55L, 45L, 57L, 17L, 19L, 2L, 31L, 41L, 26L, 
29L, 16L, 47L, 52L, 44L, 29L, 61L, 25L, 55L, 8L, 5L, 56L, 45L, 
51L, 25L, 11L, 26L, 35L, 33L, 41L, 71L, 35L, 63L, 38L, 32L, 53L, 
31L, 52L, 44L, 34L, 50L, 40L, 21L, 36L, 76L, 40L, 23L, 42L, 25L, 
14L, 58L, 38L, 37L, 69L, 46L, 46L, 49L, 42L, 28L, 55L, 13L, 45L, 
12L, 42L, 32L, 11L, 32L, 36L, 61L, 19L, 28L, 31L, 35L, 22L, 15L, 
50L, 64L, 32L, 59L, 33L, 24L, 19L, 49L, 36L, 26L, 57L, 57L, 34L, 
29L, 7L, 30L, 42L, 47L, 53L, 55L, 55L, 35L, 26L, 20L, 55L, 61L, 
43L, 31L, 30L, 52L, 27L, 63L, 25L, 47L, 63L, 23L, 2L, 47L, 12L, 
37L, 34L, 46L, 30L, 62L, 52L, 27L, 3L, 59L, 50L, 5L, 34L, 23L
), levels = c("16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", 
"46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", 
"57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
"68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", 
"79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", 
"90", "91", "93", "N.C.   "), class = "factor"), CIS.P3 = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), levels = c("Mejor", "(NO LEER) Igual", "Peor", "N.S.", 
"N.C."), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2787L))
```

To which I obtain the following graphical result, which is quite incongruent:
[image: Graph] .

Translating from Spanish, the name of the first 3 categories (above) are 'Better', 'Same', and 'Worse', respectively. Therefore, if the age interval "30-44" fares 'better' in the 1st category, there should be a lower number of answers 'worse' for "30-44" in the 3rd one.

Does anyone know, by chance, what is wrong with my code, so that I get such results?

I hope I have expressed myself clearly enough.

Many thanks in advance!

**Addendum**

I would like to give credit to @RuiBarradas and @Quinten for helping me with the original code. This is much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you say that *"Therefore, if the age interval "30-44" fares 'better' in the 1st category, there should be a lower number of answers 'worse' for "30-44" in the 3rd one"*? This is not at all true. As an example consider a survey on income categorized as "low", "medium", "high". If there are more individuals ages 30-44 in the "low" category then there should be less individuals of the same age in the "high" category? This is not at all evident.

Comment: *Disclosure: I'm mentioning one of my answers.* Also, in the posted code you have used the code of answers to other questions, [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73839295/8245406) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73845707/8245406) by user [Quinten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14282714/quinten) without **(a)  giving credits, like a link to the originals** and (b) accepting those answers.

Comment: Dear, @RuiBarradas! Thank you for your useful comments! I will most definitely take care of the giving credits aspect. Regarding your first point, the reason why I am sure that there must be an error in the code is because I have tried contrasting the age intervals (P20) with other situations (for, example, P12, which does not appear here, but which represents the prospective indivual situation of Spanish consumers), and I have obtained exactly the same graph in all cases. This surely cannot be possible!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If the Spanish age pyramid is full in the 30-44 age range, then you would expect many answers to have greater bars in that age range and this is not related to that question's categories, right? This is not an universal truth. For instance, if you are asking "Job situation", there are more "retired" in the older population, and more "employed" or "unemployed" in the 30-44 population.

Comment: Dear, @RuiBarradas! I agree with your insight, but the thing is that, previous to this, I also compared the socioeconomic perception of Spanish people according to how they see it currently versus 6 months ago, and how they see it being in the future. In these 2 cases, there are huge differences between how they see it individually, and for our country, Spain, as a whole. Therefore, the graphs cannot be exactly the same. As such, I am convinced that there must unfortunately be some error in how you modelled P20. I apologise for any possible inconvenience, and I much appreciate your help!

Comment: I still don't agree with your conclusion, the graph shows pessimism and that pessimism is transversal to the population in general irrespective of their age. This is quite possible. As a side note, I believe that in this case a percentages plot, not counts, is easier to read.

Comment: Yes, but again, the thing is that when I analyse the future socioeconomic perception, taking P20 (age intervals) into account, I do not get even a similar graph. It is literally exactly the same! There must be at least some small difference!

Comment: OK, that made it completely clear. In the plot you are not plotting `P3` by `P20`, `ggplot(aes(x = P20_fac)) + geom_bar()` plots `P20` only. When you facet by `P3` you subdivide age by sentiment but the bars still represent age counts only.

Comment: Thank you so much, @RuiBarradas! Please, could you help me modify the code so I can represent both ```P20_fac``` and ```P3```? I see the problem, but I'm quite new to R, and this coding task has clearly exceeded my current knowledge of R. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.
First, take a look at the data.

- There are no missing values in `P20`;
- There is a very small number of `"Peor"` in `P3`. That's why the bars in the plots below are missing or so small that they are not visible.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

CIS_data_5$CIS.P3 <- sub("\\(NO LEER\\) ", "", CIS_data_5$CIS.P3)
labs <- c("Mejor", "Igual", "Peor", "N.S.", "N.C.")
CIS_data_5$CIS.P3 <- factor(CIS_data_5$CIS.P3, labels = labs)

P20 <- as.integer(as.character(CIS_data_5$CIS.P20))
range(P20)
#> [1] 16 93
anyNA(P20)
#> [1] FALSE

P20labs <- c("16-29", "30-44", "45-64", ">65", "N.C.")
cut_points <- c(16, 30, 45, 65, Inf)

i <- findInterval(P20, cut_points)
P20_fac <- P20labs[i]
P20_fac[is.na(P20)] <- P20labs[length(P20labs)]
P20_fac <- factor(P20_fac, levels = P20labs)

CIS_data_5$CIS.P20 <- P20
CIS_data_5$P20_range <- P20_fac

CIS_data_5 %>%
  filter(CIS.P3 == "Peor") %>%
  count(P20_range, CIS.P3)
#>   P20_range CIS.P3 n
#> 1     45-64   Peor 2
#> 2       >65   Peor 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

### The plots

Below are two plots, a percentages plot and a counts one. The percentages are on the total table, not per each level of `P3`.
I plot the percentages bar plot using package `scales` to label the axis.

```r
CIS_data_5 %>%
  group_by(P20_range, CIS.P3) %>%
  summarise(Percentage = n()/nrow(CIS_data_5), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(P20_range, Percentage)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  xlab("Current VS Past Individual Situation Based on Age") +
  ylab("Percentage") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ CIS.P3) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(CIS_data_5, aes(P20_range)) +
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("Current VS Past Individual Situation Based on Age") +
  ylab("Count") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ CIS.P3) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is an amazing proposed solution, @RuiBarradas! Thank you so very much for your effort! The only thing that begs the question in your code is why, for example, "Peor" ("Worse") camp is completely blank for respondents of ages "16-29" and "30-44". There must surely be at least some people who responded that their socioeconomic situation has worsened among them. This is a sample of 2787 respondents, after all.

Comment: I am sorry for making so many questions, by the way! I greatly appreciate your time and your effort in helping me out!

Comment: @ArtUr693 Those are percentages per group of `P3`, in each panel they add up to 100%.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I was looking at the data the other way around. Still, and I am much sorry for bothering you, but I don't understand why there are some intervals are blank. The category "Peor" ("Worse") is the one that troubles me the most. Thank you very much for everything you're doing!

Comment: Other than that, everything is perfect, @RuiBarradas!

Comment: @ArtUr693 The first answer had `"Peor"` with two big bars because the counts of 2 and 1 had become 2/sum(2, 1) = 66.67% and 1/sum(2,1) = 33.33%. I think the plots are now much better at conveying the information present in the data.

Comment: I see... I am sorry, you're probably hating me by now, but the thing is that there is something wrong with the data. In my original data, the number of respondents ```"N.C."``` ("Don't Answer") was really low, while in your data visualization this number is extraordinarily high. Also, I badly need information on ```"Peor"```, I cannot just leave it in blank. Once again, please receive my tremendous thanks for your effort!

Comment: By the way, I agree with you, @RuiBarradas, I definitely think that "percentage" is a better way of representing the data.

Comment: And by _original data_ I mean the one that I represented visually without taking the age variable into account, just the _current versus past individual situation_ of the respondents in the sample.

Comment: I've actually been thinking, and maybe it's a case of mislabelling: ```N.C.``` data visualization actually corresponds to ```Peor``` data. This would absolutely make sense!

Comment: @ArtUr693 There are only 3 P3 rows with "N.C.", rows 1099 1158 1577. But i'll rerun the code with that new information. Done, `CIS.P3 == "N.S."` are the biggest groups and the plots are completely different.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything, @RuiBarradas! You've helped me a great, a great deal!